# pandoc - generate PDF on Arch Linux: "auto expansion is only possible with scalable fonts"

Tags: pdf, markdown, pandoc

I want to generate on my Arch Linux with pandoc a pdf document from markdown.

Everytime, when I want to generate the pdf file, I get this error message.

```
markus@markus-pc:~/workspace/github.com/volker-raschek/tgdb_ws1617$ pandoc uebung_02.md -f markdown_github --latex-engine=pdflatex -o uebung_02.pdf
! pdfTeX error (font expansion): auto expansion is only possible with scalable 
fonts.
\AtBegShi@Output ...ipout \box \AtBeginShipoutBox 
                                              \fi \fi 
l.163 \begin{Highlighting}[]

pandoc: Error producing PDF
```

So, the error message say more, thats a latex error, but I don't know how can I specify about pandoc some latex options to use the latex lm package durning my pdf generation.

Other thread with the [same error](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10706/pdftex-error-font-expansion-auto-expansion-is-only-possible-with-scalable), but not with pandoc.

Comment: Okay, I have fixed it. It's neccessary to install on arch linux texlive-fontsextra with pacman.

Comment: feel free to post this as an answer and accept it...

Comment: Same thing here, but I've installed texlive not from pacman, but from CTAN tlmgr... So I don't know which font in texlive-fontsextra shall be installed to solve the issue !

Comment: Here is the PKGBUILD file on the arch linux repo. 
https://git.archlinux.org/svntogit/packages.git/tree/trunk?h=packages/texlive-fontsextra

There is the file `texlive-fontsextra.maps` which contains all fonts. Maybe you can try to make a diff between your `texlive-fontsextra` package and the arch linux package to locale the missing fonts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have fixed my problem.

It's necessary to install the package `texlive-fontsextra` about `pacman`.

**Solution**

Typ in terminal:

`pacman -S texlive-fontsextra`

Comment: it's so incredible to me that after 5 and a half years from original truggle of yours I can benefit from you providing solution. Thank you!